# Dynamically generated excel file download working on local machine but after deployment its not working on IIS 7?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, export-to-excel

I have created asp.net mvc4 + angularjs project which is used for export to excel functionality from dynamically created html table. Its working on local machine but after deployment its gives me error like below,

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

For creating excel file dynamically I am using below code-

public class ExcelResult : ActionResult
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string HTMLContent { get; set; }

```
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(HTMLContent);
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }

}

public ExcelResult ExportInvalidDataToExcel(string HTMLContent)
    {
        return new ExcelResult
        {
            HTMLContent = TempData["ExcelData"].ToString(),
            FileName = "InvalidInvoiceDataReport.xls"
        };
    }
```

In my Angularjs controller the method is as follows,

```
//Export
    $scope.export = function () {

        var config = { method: 'POST', url: 'api/MSReport/getMSReport', data: { currentPage: $scope.msreport.currentPage, pageSize: $scope.msreport.pageSize, startRow: $scope.msreport.startRow, stopRow: $scope.msreport.stopRow, IsExport: true } };

        HttpFactory.getDataByHttpPost(config).then(function (resp) {

            if (resp.status) {
                window.location = "http://" + location.host + "/api/MSReport/ExportToExcel";
            }

        });

    };
```

Please help me to out of this.

Thanks in advance,
Mohinesh Tayade

Comment: This application deployed on IIS 7

Comment: You need to show some code, or at the very least detail how you're generating the excel file.

Comment: when I am running it on local machine then the excel file is downloading but after deployment on IIS 7 its not working. I have spent 2 days to find out the issue.

Comment: Brendan Green ???

Comment: First of all extremely sorry for delayed reply,  because of some restrictions not able to share the code.